# How to catch ajax server failures in kendo?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
<script>
        function grid_errorHandler(e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    </script>

  @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
                .Name("ResultsGrid")
                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .Events(events => events.Error("grid_errorHandler"))
```

However when the ajax call fails (due to invalid credentials), I dont get any logs, is there any way I can catch an error on the ajax request for the kendo ui grid?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
 function grid_errorHandler(e) {
     console.log(e.status);
 }
```

Hope this helps, you can find more info [here](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/events/error).